# Resolving Promise Angular 2

Tags: forms, angular-promise, angular2-forms

I have the following problem.

In a function I have a promise as a return type. This function is in the class Hierarchy.

```
updateNodeValues(entity: String, data: {}): Promise<any>{
    let jsonBody = JSON.stringify(data);
    let url = environment.endpointCore + '/api/' + entity + '/' + data['id'];

    return this.http.put(url, jsonBody, this.options)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => {
        return response;
      })
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

This function is in class node.

```
onSubmit(): void{
    var currentForm = this.form.value;
    var entityName = this.inflection.classify(this.node.type).toLowerCase();
    var requiredData = {};

    for(var i = 0; i < this.formItems.length; i++){
      this.formItems[i].value = currentForm[Object.keys(currentForm)[i]];
    }

    for(var i=0; i<this.formItems.length; i++){
      requiredData[this.globalService.camelize(this.formItems[i].label)] = this.formItems[i].value
    }

    Promise.resolve(this.hierarchyService.updateNodeValues(entityName, requiredData)).then(response => {
      alert(response.ok);
      if(response.ok){
        this.globalService.showSuccessMessage('Values updated');
        this.refreshGui(requiredData);
      }
    });
    this.editMode = false;
  }
```

The problem is that when i try to resolve promise and invoke `this.refreshGui(requireddata)` nothing is happening. I have read about how the fat arrow is preserving the 'context' of this, and I do not understand why invoking this method is not doing anything, while invoking `successMessage` produces expected outcome.

The method that I am invoking looks like this, and it is also in the class node.

```
private refreshGui(data: {}){
    this._node.data = data;
    this.objectProperties = new Array();
    this.nodeChildren = new Array();
    for (var property in data) {
      var propertyValue = data[property];
      if (propertyValue instanceof Array) {
        this.nodeChildren.push({label: property,  value: "total: ".concat(propertyValue.length.toString())});
      } else {
        this.objectProperties.push({label: property, value: propertyValue});
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I found to be working was to implement custom event. The problem was that within the async callback resolution, the context of what `this` is would "get lost". The fat arrow enabled me to invoke class method with this, but the properties within the would be "lost". Because of this reason I have took the logic from the method, and put it in the callback part and set expected and needed results in some variable. This variable was passed to my custom event and set to class variable in the custom event handler appropriately.